# Want to retain the red color even after we closed the browser

Tags: javascript, html

```js
 

var add  = [];
var tbl = document.getElementById("seat");

if (tbl != null) {

    for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
        {
            tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick  = function () {
         
         this.bgColor="red";  //when click the particular seat number, table cell color changed to red
                     
         add.push( this.innerHTML );
         
         getval();
             
            };
        }        
    }
}

    
function getval () {  
    document.getElementById("userinput").value = add.join(","); //add that seat number to array with comma
}
```

```html
 
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Ticket Booking</title>
<style>
body {
    background-color:lightgreen ;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form action="Booking" method="post">
Enter your name:<input type="text" name="name"><br></br>
select your movie:<select name="movies">
<option value="Aval">Aval</option>
  <option value="Avan">Avan</option>
  <option value="SMS">SMS</option>
  <option value="Amman">Amman</option>
  <option value="Amman">Balloon</option>
</select><br></br>
select your show time:<select name="showtime">
<option value="9AM">9AM</option>
  <option value="1PM">1PM</option>
  <option value="4PM">4PM</option>
  <option value="8PM">8PM</option>
</select><br></br>
<TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="50%" id="seat"bgcolor="green" >
   <TR ALIGN = "CENTER">Seating Arrangement</TR>
   <TR ALIGN = "CENTER" >
      <TD>A1 </TD> //These are seat numbers
      <TD >A2</TD>
      <TD>A3</TD>
      <TD >A4</TD>
      <TD>A5</TD>
      
   </TR>
    <TR ALIGN = "CENTER" >
      <TD>B1</TD>
      <TD>B2</TD>
      <TD>B3</TD>
      <TD>B4</TD>
      <TD>B5</TD>
      
   </TR>
   <TR ALIGN = "CENTER" >
      <TD >C1</TD>
      <TD>C2</TD>
      <TD>C3</TD>
      <TD>C4</TD>
      <TD>C5</TD>
      
   </TR>
    <TR ALIGN = "CENTER" >
      <TD>D1</TD>
      <TD>D2</TD>
      <TD>D3</TD>
      <TD>D4</TD>
      <TD>D5</TD>
      
   </TR>
    
    <TR ALIGN = "CENTER" >
      <TD>E1</TD>
      <TD>E2</TD>
      <TD>E3</TD>
      <TD>E4</TD>
      <TD>E5</TD>
      </TR>
  </TABLE><br></br>
Enter your seat number : <input type="text" name="seatno" id="userinput"><br></br>
```

This is where I am stuck.
When I clicked on seat number, color changed from green to red,
but when I refresh the page its not retaining the red color. 
I want to retain the red color and when the another user click on it,
it should alert "Its already booked". Please help me in this.

Booked tickets should be in red.

Comment: Store your value somewhere, `localStorage`, database...

Comment: Are you saving the selected seats to a database?

Comment: yes. using java servlet am getting these details from jsp and stored it in database using Dao class(Mysql database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function load_colors() {
  var seats = document.getElementsByClassName('td_seat');

  for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {

    seats[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.bgColor = 'red';
      try {

        localStorage.setItem(this.id, 'red');
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("StackOverflow snippet doesn't allow localStorage");
      }

    }, false);
    try {


      var color = localStorage.getItem(seats[i].id);
      if (color) {
        seats[i].bgColor = color;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("StackOverflow snippet doesn't allow localStorage");
    }

  }


}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onload="load_colors();">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='td_seat' id='seat_1'>1</td>
      <td class='td_seat' id='seat_2'>2</td>
      <td class='td_seat' id='seat_3'>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='td_seat' id='seat_4'>4</td>
      <td class='td_seat' id='seat_5'>5</td>
      <td class='td_seat' id='seat_6'>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='td_seat' id='seat_7'>7</td>
      <td class='td_seat' id='seat_8'>8</td>
      <td class='td_seat' id='seat_9'>9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

One way to do that is to make use of `localStorage` object.

I updated my answer so that it should work as you described. However, stackOverflow snippets are sandboxed and can't access `localStorage` object. But if you try it at your end, it should work fine.

Comment: One users localstorage does not change it for other users.

Comment: I was just giving an inspiration. Fixed my answer to account for your comment. @MunimMunna

Comment: very kind of you, I will try this

Comment: Its not working. Actually while clicking am getting seat numbers with comma operator and i stored it in database

Comment: @Pallavi any errors in Javascript console? What browser are you using?

Comment: am running in tomcat

Comment: Please add snippet.

Comment: @Pallavi I added snippet and edited my answer. read carefully

Comment: @Pallavi if you find my answer useful, please accept or upvote. Otherwise, please share with us if you found a different solution.

Comment: @Pallavi can you please accept my answer or at least upvote it?